# Exporting Mixamo rigged meshes giving offset

Tags: armature, export, transforms, weight-painting, mixamo

I have been working on some character models for a game project I'm about to start, and I decided I wanted to use Mixamo to animate since I have no budget for the project.

I did not like the results I was getting from the auto rig from Mixamo so I took the exported FBX back into blender and adjusted the skeleton and manually weight painted the meshes.

In blender the result is nice and I can retarget animations to the modified skeletons in unity easy enough so I don't have to worry about importing all of my animations into blender to adjust them.

rest and pose in blender
[image]
[image]

When I export the fbx I am getting an odd result. The character model and clothes appear offset downwards, but the hair seems correctly placed. The hair is paired to the head bone specifically while the other parts have armature modifiers and weight paints for the armature.

[image]

The other thing I have noticed is that the imported armature has some transforms and scaling that came with it from the auto rig. Applying the transforms makes the poses break, and may interfere with retargeting in the future, and in my test where I cleared my pose and applied all transforms the export problem remained.

[image]

So my best guess is there is something in the way weight painted rigs export that is different from just objects parented to bones, but I'm planning to pair empties to the bones in unity for the hair and like, however exporting without those paired to the bones still results in the model being offset down below the ground.

My export settings are

- path mode (copy/embed textures)
- selected objects (armature/mesh)
- apply scaling(FBX Units Scale)
- Z forward
- only deform bones
- bake animations (Key All Bones only)

TLDR; My FBX exports wacky and I'm at a loss